# Highcharts: Conditional tooltip based on multiple checking chart is drilldown or not

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

```
 formatter: function() {
                           return (this.hasOwnProperty("drilldown") ? 'Count of user' : 'count of number' + this.point.y);
                         }
                   },
```

I just want to change tooltip text based on drilldown condition.

I have set Xaxis name by add event in chart and it's working So what should i do for tooltip ??

```
events: {drilldown: function(e) {
                              this.xAxis[0].setTitle({
                                text: 'Accounts'
                              });
                            },
                            drillup: function(e) {
                              this.xAxis[0].setTitle({
                                text: 'Source'
                              });
                            }
                          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `ddDupes` chart's property in tooltip's formatter. For example:

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      const chart = this.series.chart;
      if (chart.ddDupes && chart.ddDupes.length) {
        return 'Drilled down';
      }

      return 'Not drilled down';
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7abL0en4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter